# Multiple insert in a loop in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

```
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) 
{
    keyword = tokens.nextToken();
    System.out.println("File= "+fileid+" Keyword=" + keyword);
    stmt.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT into TEXTVALUEINVERTEDINDEX " + "(FILEID, KEYWORD) values ('"
        + fileid + "', '" + keyword + "')"
    );      
}
```

This is the loop in which I'm updating the rows. The problem I'm facing is that when i run this only 1 value gets updated and when I comment the `stmt.executeUpdate()` line it displays all the possible entries in the database.

Comment: What happens if you replace "stmt.executeUpdate" with "System.out.println" and try executing the output of that directly through your SQL client? That'll tell you if the problem is client-side or server-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. Make sure the sentence is not throwing any Exceptions when running by surrounding it with a `try/catch` block:

```
try {
    stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT into TEXTVALUEINVERTEDINDEX " + 
         "(FILEID, KEYWORD) "+"values ('"+fileid+"', '"+keyword+"')"); 
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should also consider using a `PreparedStament` instead since its use is very appropriate for your described scenario:

Something like this:

```
String sql = "insert into textvalueinvertedindex (fileid, keyword) values (?,?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
while (tokes.hasMoreTokens()) {
    keywords = tokens.nextToken();
    pstmt.setString(1, fileid);
    pstmt.setString(2, keyword);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
pstmt.close();
```

Comment: Actually i pasted only the loop code..the try catch block is present there is no exception being thrown

Answer (score 5):

You need to use preparedStatements...

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into TEXTVALUEINVERTEDINDEX (FILEID, KEYWORD) values(?,?)");
while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) 
    {
        keyword = tokens.nextToken();
        System.out.println("File= "+fileid+"    Keyword="+keyword);

        pStmt.setString(1, fileid); //This might be pStmt.SetInt(0, fileid) depending on teh type of fileid)
        pStmt.setString(2, keyword);

        pStmt.executeUpdate();
    }
```

then using this you can extend to us batch update...

```
PreparedStatement pStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT into TEXTVALUEINVERTEDINDEX (FILEID, KEYWORD) values(?,?)");
    while (tokens.hasMoreTokens()) 
        {
            keyword = tokens.nextToken();
            System.out.println("File= "+fileid+"    Keyword="+keyword);

            pStmt.setString(1, fileid); //This might be pStmt.SetInt(0, fileid) depending on teh type of fileid)
            pStmt.setString(2, keyword);

            pStmt.addBatch();
        }
pStmt.executeBatch();
```

Not sure why your code isn't working though - but this will probably help in the long run...

Comment: pStmt.setString(0, fileid);
here its giving an exception column not found.the fileid ive declared as String fileid

Comment: We have to give pStmt.setString(1, fileid);
pStmt.setString(2, keyword);

Comment: Edited the original - this is the problem with working with multplie languages, I was getting mixed up with .Net which is 0 indexed...

Comment: pStmt.addBatch();
pStmt.executeBatch(); Is not a good option when size of data is large causing Out of Memory exception. However Option #1 for update is doing as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all updates to be applied at once you can use batch execution, [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/tjvbtupd.htm) is an example

Comment: strange, it work for me. anyway just google for "java jdbc addBatch" and pick any page you like.

Answer (score 0):

Your date range and filter selection contained no results.